# Discord word filter bot doesn't delete anything

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I made a discord.py bot for one of our members, as a joke. im testing it out and it doesnt work at all. can someone tell me what can be wrong with this code?

```
from http import client
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 await client.process_commands(message) # add this if also using command decorators
 if message.author.id == 300677572683890688 and "tranime" in message.content.lower():
     await message.delete()
     await message.channel.send(f"You are in the process of behavioural therapy. please do not attempt to bypass it, {message.author.mention}")
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work at all". Does not send the expected response? Does not come online? Is lazy and literally does not work? Its too ambiguous.

Comment: ah my bad, it does come online but it doesn't delete the message or do send a message.

Comment: Try putting `await client.process_commands(message)` at the very end of your `on_message`. It tends to stop the program from working if it's at the beginning

Comment: like this?
async def on_message(message): 
    if message.author.id == 300677572683890688 and "tranime" in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"You are in the process of behavioural therapy. please do not attempt to bypass it, {message.author.mention}")
        await client.process_commands(message)

Comment: update i kinda tried another snippet and it works not, i got one question though is there a way to automate it blocking bypasses (like tr4nime) or do i gotta add them all manually

Comment: You should edit your question to include your code, it's nearly impossible to read it in the comment format.

Comment: You're running the bot before the `on_message`... How do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 1):

The structure, how you build the bot, is wrong in many ways, that could cause the error.

To run the bot,

```py
client.run(TOKEN)
```

always belongs at the **end** of your code!

To process commands, you put

```py
await client.process_commands(message)
```

at the end of your `on_message` event, even though this is not necessary here as you just use `discord.Client()`.

**A new structure could be:**

```py
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

@client.event
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author.id == 300677572683890688 and "tranime" in message.content.lower():
        await message.delete()
        await message.channel.send(f"Your message here")
    await client.process_commands(message)

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The code should also be indented correctly, otherwise there may be problems.

Comment: Why does `await client.process_commands(message)` need to be at the bottom? With the way it is now, you might gets errors as the message gets deleted before it can process commands (not that any commands are being used in this code).

Comment: @Benjin From the docs: "*To fix this, add a `bot.process_commands(message)` line at the end of your on_message*" - I am just saying what the docs say to not get into any trouble. All the examples I have seen so far do it like this. There can be special cases where this might not apply but it should not cause any trouble.

Comment: I believe the docs only address why `on_message` is not working, not that `await client.process_commands(message)` should always be used at the end of the event. In this case it could cause errors since `message` may be deleted before getting to process, so something like `else: await client.process_commands(message)` could be used to avoid it (or placing it somewhere else). Regardless, it's not relevant to this question since no commands are used.

Comment: @Benjin I do not know if that is really useful as commands and `on_message` differ in some ways, but thanks for pointing this out. We should then keep in mind that we have to use `elif` statements for the other `on_message` events, so we can use `else` in the end.

Comment: thank you so much! ill keep that in mind. do you know if theres any way to make the bot also delete words similiar to the blacklisted word?

Comment: @Debiuu1312 You can create a list and check within a loop if the word is in a list.